# Trying to get Arg[1 + I a] -> ArcTan[a]

Tags: replacement, complex

Can Mathematica evaluate `Arg[1+ I a]` when `a` is a positive real in order to get `ArcTan[a]`?

For example (this is much simpler than the code I'm working with):

```
ComplexExpand[Im[1/Sqrt[1 + I a]]]
```

outputs

> ```
> -(Sin[1/2 Arg[1 + I a]]/(1 + a^2)^(1/4)).
> ```

This is a calculation in the middle of my code, and I'm too lazy to replace `Arg[1+ i a]` for `ArcTan[a]` manually every time the code is run. Moreover, in the following lines of that code I would like to have only real variables in order to use the function `Simplify` instead of `ComplexExpand`, otherwise I get

```
ComplexExpand[ArcTan[a/b]]
```

> ```
> -(1/2) Arg[1 - (I a)/b] + 1/2 Arg[1 + (I a)/b].
> ```

Note that

```
Simplify[-(Sin[1/2 Arg[1 + I a]]/(1 + a^2)^(1/4)), a ∈ Reals]
```

doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does this simple replacement do what you want?  If not, why?  `Arg[1 + I a] /. Arg[1 + I*x_] :> ArcTan[x]`

Comment: Yes! It does, as well as `Arg[1 + I a]  /. Arg -> arg`, where 'arg' is given below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a direct replacement (using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)) may be adequate:

```
Arg[1 + I a] /. Arg[1 + I*x_] :> ArcTan[x]
```

> ```
> ArcTan[a]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else posted a working answer yesterday, which is gone today; maybe it was deleted by the author for some reason. The solution was to define a function

```
arg[num_] := ArcTan[ComplexExpand[Im[num]]/ComplexExpand[Re[num]]]
```